# SQL practices to persist the reference and remove referenced object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I designing a SQL db system(with Postgre) and I have a question about what is the common practice to create a relationship / reference that can persist even when referenced objects are deleted.

For example, there is a UserORM, and ActivityORM, and UserActivityRelation. ActivityORM holds user.id as foreign key to tell who created the activity, and relation table is about which users should know about the activity.

Now, if I want to remove the actor from db, I still want ActivityORM and the relation table to persist so that other users can still know about the activities. I want to know what is the most common / best practice to design such system. Simple answers might be not assigning them as foreign keys, or create an inactive state, but I wonder if there is any better ways.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, removing the problematical foreign key constraints would solve the immediate problem of deleting either users or activities on either side of the bridge table.  But then this would allow broken relationships to end up in your database.

I propose using soft deletion here.  Add an `active` bit column to both the `UserORM` and `ActivityORM` tables.  Then, when you need to delete a user or activity, just mark that record as inactive.  This would guarantee that the key relationships do not get broken during the deletion.  And this approach would also let you view relationships which used to exist, prior to any deletions.

Comment: well.. I guess that's the only way :( Thanks!